# FIFO String Allocation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, allocation, fifo

I am currently having a problem with the program that I'm creating right now. I already looked for answers, but it's different from what I want to happen because the given here are strings.

We were asked to create a FIFO allocation and here is the expected flow of the program as a console application:

Enter no. of page frames: 2

Enter no. of pages to be inserted: 4

Page to be inserted: A

Inserted in frame 1. Interrupt generated.

Page to be inserted: B

Inserted in frame 2. Interrupt generated.

Page to be inserted: A

Insertion failed. A is a resident page.

Page to be inserted: C

Inserted in frame 1. Interrupt generated.

According to the FIFO allocation algorithm, it will remove the earliest page inserted in the frame if you insert a new different page. If the page is already in the frame then the page insertion will be rejected.

I already made one although I'm currently stuck in trying figure out how to find the earliest inserted element in the array.

I hope that you can help me. I already spent a lot of time but I just don't know what to do. Here's my code.:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int f, p, interrupt;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of frames: ");
        f = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] frame = new string[f];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of pages: ");
        p = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {


            Console.WriteLine("Page to be inserted: ");

            string x = Console.ReadLine();

            if (frame.Contains(x))
            {

                Console.WriteLine(x + " is a resident page.");


            }
            else {

                frame[i] = x;
                Console.WriteLine("Inserted in frame " + (i + 1) + ". Interrupt generated"));
                interrupt +=1;

            }
        }





        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you not try to use Queue<string> for the purpose. It has built in functionality for FIFO processing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Do not use an array. The "First In First Out" model is a queue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

If you use a Queue it will retain order. You're only allowed to remove the first in item. The concept is that it works like a traffic queue, the object at the front must go before anything else can move. Before queuing just do a `for each` or LINQ query to ensure that the item is not a duplicate. The `Dequeue` method will always remove the first item added to the queue.

```
 // for each example. For LINQ just use Where then check the length of the IEnumerable
 // if it 0 then item is unique.
 bool duplicate = false;
 foreach (string s in MyQueue)
 {
     if (s == inputString)
         duplicate = true;
 }

 if (!duplicate)
     MyQueue.Enqueue(inputString);



 // to get first item added simply do
 string firstIn = MyQueue.Dequeue();
```

Comment: Our professor didn't teach us this concept, but I will study it so I can apply it in my program. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @PatrickJamesLim yes, I find that somewhat odd. I was taught this stuff by writing a; stack, queue, linked list, hash table, and binary search tree in C++. A queue is definitely what you want and it's surprising to me you weren't instructed to use it since it is the model used for FIFO in computer science. *Hint when he asks you to do LIFO on your next assignment use a stack :p

Comment: I'm actually an IT student that's why we didn't get into further details regarding the Operating System concepts. And it sucks because the farthest programming concept that we got is array and a little introduction to OOP programming. I have to learn the succeeding concepts by myself and it's quite hard. I'm trying to guess that he'll ask us to make a program using LRU next time. Thanks again! >.<

Comment: @PatrickJamesLim the wikipedia articles on data structures and operations you do on them are pretty good. If you're looking for conceptual information there is plenty there. All of these things are common programming constructs so they're definitely worth reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use something other than arrays, like [evanmcdonnal suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444987/848330). Anyway, using your code, you need to add a separate variable to detect when you reach the frame limit:

```
    int j= 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {


        Console.WriteLine("Page to be inserted: ");

        string x = Console.ReadLine();

        if (frame.Contains(x))
        {

            Console.WriteLine(x + " is a resident page.");


        }
        else {

            if(j >= f)
                int insertAt = 0;
            else
                int insertAt = j;

            frame[insertAt ] = x;
            Console.WriteLine("Inserted in frame " + (insertAt + 1) + ". Interrupt generated"));
            interrupt +=1;

            j++;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your code confuses the data structure and its methods with the actual program. You need to decompose your program more. You need first to create a class that implements your FIFO queue. Validate that it behaves as you expect it to. Then, write the actual program you need, using that class.

The data structure you actually want, would seem to be a queue, as noted by others.

Contrary to what some have said ("do not use an array"), queues of fixed capacity are trivial to implement using an array as a backing store.

You need to use your array as a circular buffer. In addition to the array itself, you need to track 3 other pieces of information:

- The offset of the *head* of the queue. This is the least recently added item in the queue and would be the first item removed.
- The offset of the *tail* of the queue. This is the most recently added item in the queue and would be the last item removed.

Theoretically, you don't any more information than this. However, there's a singularity in that the state at which the head and the tail collide is either a 'queue empty' state or a 'queue full state'. As a result, you need to track the length of the queue.

The `Dequeue()` operation is easy:

- Check the queue length. If it is less than 1, the queue is empty. Throw an underflow exception. Otherwise, continue.
- The head offset is the next item due for removal. Get that item from the array.
- Clear the array slot, so no dangling references are left that might prevent the object from being garbage collected.
- Decrement the length.
- Increment the head pointer, wrapping to zero if it exceeds the array's capacacity - 1. The easiest way to do this is via modulo arithmetic:

  ```
  OffsetHead = (OffsetHead+1) % MyBackingStoreArray.Length ;
  ```
- Return the removed item.

The `Enqueue()` operation isn't much more complicated, though there is one special case, when the queue is empty:

- Check the queue length.
- If the queue length is 0, add the first item to the queue:

  - Add the item to the array at offset 0.
  - set the offset to the head and the offset to the tail to 0.
- if the queue length is > 0,

  - The offset to the first free slot is 1 past the current tail pointer, modulo the array length as above.
  - If that computed offset collides with the offset to the head of the queue, the queue is full: throw an overflow exception.
  - Otherwise, add the new item to the array at that computed offset.
  - Set the offset to the tail to the compute offset.
- Finally, increment the queue length.

Other operations you might want to implement:

- `Peek()`. It can sometimes be useful to examine the next item in the queue without dequeueing it.
- `Contains()`. Formally, a queue is an opaque data structure. You can only add items to at the tail and remove them from the head. However, it's can be useful to check is something is already enqueued, though I'd argue that it would be a better design to decorate a queue with set-like semantics.

Also useful to expose the queue's current length as a property.

You should be able to figure it out from there. I'll amend this answer with an implementation tomorrow, if you've not figured it out.

. . .

As promised, here's an implementation of fixed-length queue:

```
class ArrayQueue<T>
{
  private T[] backingStore ;
  private int head ; // offset to head of the queue (least recently added item)
  private int tail ; // offset to tail of the queue (most recently added item)

  /// <summary>
  /// current queue length
  /// </summary>
  public int Length   { get ; private set ; }
  /// <summary>
  /// Maximum Queue Length
  /// </summary>
  public int Capacity { get { return this.backingStore.Length ; } }

  /// <summary>
  /// Add an item to the queue
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="value"></param>
  public void Enqueue( T value )
  {

    if ( Length == 0 )
    {
      this.backingStore[0] = value ;
      this.head  = 0 ;
      this.tail  = 0 ;
    }
    else
    {
      // A head/tail collision means the queue is full: throw an overflow exception
      if ( this.tail == this.head ) { throw new OverflowException("Maximum capacity exceeded") ; }
      this.backingStore[this.tail] = value ;
    }

    // increment the tail and the length, wrapping the tail point if necessary
    this.tail = (this.tail+1) % this.backingStore.Length ;
    ++this.Length ;

    return ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Remove the next (oldest) item from the queue
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public T Dequeue()
  {
    if ( this.Length < 1 ) { throw new InvalidOperationException("queue is empty") ; }

    T value = this.backingStore[head] ;
    this.backingStore[head] = default(T) ; // lose the reference so the newly dequeued item can be garbage-collected.

    --this.Length;
    this.head = (this.head+1) % this.backingStore.Length ;

    return value ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Examine the head of the queue, without removing it
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public T Peek()
  {
    if ( this.Length < 1 ) {  throw new InvalidOperationException("queue is empty") ; }

    T value = this.backingStore[head] ;
    return value ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Clear/Empty the queue
  /// </summary>
  public void Clear()
  {
    // clear any object references to the queue so they can be garbage-collected
    Array.Clear(this.backingStore,0,this.backingStore.Length);
    this.head   = 0 ;
    this.tail   = 0 ;
    this.Length = 0 ;
    return ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// indicates whether or not the specified item is present in the queue
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="value"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public bool Contains( T value )
  {
    bool found = false ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; !found && i < this.Length ; ++i )
    {
      int p = (this.head+1) % this.Capacity ;
      found = this.backingStore[p].Equals( value ) ;
    }
    return found ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Create an instance of an ArrayQueue&lt;T&gt; having the specified fixed capacity
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="capacity"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static ArrayQueue<T> CreateInstance( int capacity )
  {
    if ( capacity < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("capacity","capacity must be non-negative");

    ArrayQueue<T> instance = new ArrayQueue<T>(capacity) ;

    return instance ;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// private (and only constructor)
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="capacity"></param>
  private ArrayQueue( int capacity )
  {
    this.backingStore = new T[capacity] ;
    this.Clear() ;
    return ;
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement this now. Still, I hope that you can give me an answer tomorrow and compare it to my work. Thank you so much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I bet this will help. Open this page and use the same example there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx

Just make this change for the line under the Main() method.

```
        // Create a scheduler that uses 1 threads first-in, first-out (FIFO) execution order. 
        LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler lcts = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(1);
```